# Having a "global" variable only for session in Shiny

Tags: r, session, global-variables, shiny, session-variables

I have multiple Shiny apps with multiple sessions, and I would like to have a global variable but only across each session, not to override values between different sessions. Due to that requirement, I cannot use the `<<-` assignment operator.

The reason I need it is that I have several variables that are being used by many sourced functions, and I don't want to send them as a parameter to all of the functions.

Any ideas on how to do that?

***EDIT***

I created a simple example to better explain my problem.
Let's say this is my `server.R` file:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  source('shinyCommons.R')
  reportId <<- generateReportID()
  createLogFile()
})
```

and this is the `shinyCommons.R` functions file that **contains non-reactive functions**:

```
createLogFile <- function()
{
  system(paste(touch,reportId,".log",sep=""))
}
```

Now the problem is, that if I use the `<<-` operator, and different sessions are active at the same time, they override each other's `reportID` value. 
But if I put it in a `reactive` context, then the non-reactive functions can't reach it.

Can someone help me to understand how should I design it?
BTW - I know I can send it as a param to the function, but this is just a small example, I have a lot of vars and a lot of functions that use them

Comment: Define the objects inside the function argument of `shinyServer`. They are global to a session, but not shared between sessions.

Comment: That's what I tried, but apparently when I used <<- it was shared between sessions, I saw it on the logs of the app

Comment: It depends on *where* you are using `<<-`. Se `?"<<-"`. In the function inside `shinyServer` you define your objects with just `<-`. Inside `reactive` contexts, you use `<<-` if you want to update the value of an object. I bet that you are using `<<-` outside `reactive` (or other functions) environment and so the variable is bound to a common environment and shared between sessions.

Comment: @nicola thanks for your answer, can you please see the example I added above?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, I won the bet: you are using incorrectly the `<<-` operator. Here is a working example.

In `ui.R`:

```
barraLaterale<-sidebarPanel(
    fluidRow(column(numericInput("numObs",label="Num Obs.",value=10000,min=100,step=1),width=6),column(helpText("Something"),actionButton("Bottone",label="Go!"),width=6)),
    sliderInput("media",label="Pick gaussian mean",min=-50,max=50,value=0),
    sliderInput("varianza",label="Pick gaussian standard deviation",min=0,max=10,value=5)
)
principale<-mainPanel(plotOutput("plotRisultato"),plotOutput("plotEsatto"))
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Applicazione Prova"),
    sidebarLayout(barraLaterale,principale)
))
```

In `server.R`:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    #HERE WE DEFINE COMMON OBJECTS
    object<-0
    calcolaIstogramma<-reactive({
        rnorm(input$numObs,input$media,input$varianza)  
    })
    output$plotRisultato<-renderPlot({
        a<-input$Bottone
        variabile<-isolate(calcolaIstogramma())
        hist(variabile,breaks=50,col="blue")
    })
    output$plotEsatto<-renderPlot({
        a<-input$Bottone
        variabile<-isolate(calcolaIstogramma())
        #HERE WE ARE UPDATING THE VALUES
        object<<-object+1
        cat(object,"\n")
        plot(variabile,xlab="Variable trace",ylab="",ty="l")
    })
})
```

Open a couple of sessions when you run the app. Every time you press the button, you should see the counter on the shell. You can see that counters are not shared. Common objects are defined in the scope of the function argument of `shinyServer`. Then, inside other function/reactive contexts, you can use `<<-` to update/overwrite the values.

Comment: If I'm using it from within `shinyServer` function then it totally makes sense. But in my case, you can see that I'm trying to use it in a non-reactive expression, in a utility function that isn't an input or output object of the app. Is there any way to use a session variable in such such function?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to use the `local` option while sourcing?

This should work:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
    source('shinyCommons.R', local=TRUE)
    reportId <- generateReportID()
    createLogFile()
})
```

Please note that you should use <- instead of <<- to keep the variable in the local environment (and therefore to be independent across sessions).